# ERROR Uncaught throwable from user code: java.lang.IllegalStateException in spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have 2 streaming query like bellow

```
val streamingQuery = injectableDependencies.writeStreamDfToDeltaFile(validDF, dataPath, checkPointPath, configuration.pollingTimerSeconds, queryName, configuration.outputMode, configuration.partitionBy)

//streamingQuery for Invalid tables
val streamingQueryInvalid = injectableDependencies.writeStreamDfToDeltaFile(inValidDF, dataPathInvalid, checkPointPath, configuration.pollingTimerSeconds, queryNameInvalid, configuration.outputMode, configuration.partitionBy)

//creating valid tables
injectableDependencies.createTableOverDeltaFile(configuration.tableName, configuration.databaseName, dataPath, streamingQuery)

//creating invalid tables
injectableDependencies.createTableOverDeltaFile("Invalid"+configuration.tableName, configuration.databaseName, dataPath, streamingQueryInvalid)
```

below i am trying to write streams

```
  df
  .writeStream
  .format("DELTA")
  .option("path", dataPath)
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkPointPath)
  .partitionBy(partitionBy.getOrElse(List[String]()): _*)
  .outputMode(outputMode)
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(pollingTimerSeconds.seconds))
  .queryName(queryName)
  .start()
```

i am getting bellow error

```
ERROR Uncaught throwable from user code: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start query with id 74e6b948-bc55-419c-af42-34ef7ea015ba as another query with same id is already active. Perhaps you are attempting to restart a query from the checkpoint that is already active.
```

Can anybody please suggest what going wrong

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and solved it by ensuring that each streaming query gets its dedicated `checkpointLocation` as option in the `writeStream` call.